# Ember Data - rending one to many in template

Tags: model, ember.js, handlebars.js, one-to-many, ember-data

I am trying to return a list of all of the Sponsorship Types followed by any Partners that may be under that Sponsorship Type.  I am using the Fixture Adaptor and here are my arrays:

```
var partnersArray = [
    { id: 1, sponsorship:[1], sponsorName: 'NYT', url: 'http://nyt.com/', image: 'images/sponsors/nyt.png'},
    { id: 1, sponsorship:[2], sponsorName: 'WSJ', url: 'http://wsj.com/', image: 'images/sponsors/wsj.png'},
    { id: 1, sponsorship:[2], sponsorName: 'CNN', url: 'http://cnn.com/', image: 'images/sponsors/cnn.png'},
];
var sponsorshipArray = [
    { id: 1, sponsorshipName:'Big Dog', sponsorshipPrice:'$25,000'},
    { id: 2, sponsorshipName:'Dog', sponsorshipPrice:'$10,000'},
    { id: 3, sponsorshipName:'Canine', sponsorshipPrice:'$5,000'},
    { id: 4, sponsorshipName:'Pup', sponsorshipPrice:'$2,000'},
    { id: 5, sponsorshipName:'Puppy', sponsorshipPrice:'$1,000'},
];
```

These are my models:

```
App.Sponsorship = DS.Model.extend({
    sponsorshipName: DS.attr('string'),
    sponsorshipPrice: DS.attr('string'),
    partners: DS.hasMany('App.Partner')
});
App.Sponsorship.FIXTURES = sponsorshipArray;


App.Partner = DS.Model.extend({
    sponsorship: DS.attr('string'),
    sponsorName: DS.attr('string'),
    image: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    partnerSponsor: DS.belongsTo('App.Sponsorship'),
});
App.Partner.FIXTURES = partnersArray;
```

This is my route:

```
App.PartnersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Sponsorship.find();
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
    }
});
```

This is my Handlebars

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="partners">
        <h2>Partners</h2>
        {{#each sponsorship in controller}}
            {{sponsorship.sponsorshipName}}<br />
            {{sponsorship.partners}}<br /><br />
        {{/each}}
    </script>
```

This is my output:

```
Big Dog
<DS.ManyArray:ember345>

Dog
<DS.ManyArray:ember346>

Canine
<DS.ManyArray:ember347>

Pup
<DS.ManyArray:ember348>

Puppy
<DS.ManyArray:ember349>
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing missing here and have simplified it somewhat so that I can see where I should be adding code... any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You also need a `partners` ids array in the `sponsorshipArray`. ie:- both sides of the relationship.

```
var sponsorshipArray = [
    { id: 1, sponsorshipName:'Big Dog', sponsorshipPrice:'$25,000', partners: [1, 2, ...]}
];
```

And in the `partnersArray`, since it's a `belongsTo` relationship, use,

```
var partnersArray = [
    { id: 1, sponsorship:1, sponsorName: 'NYT', url: 'http://nyt.com/', image: 'images/sponsors/nyt.png'}
];
```

without the array.

Comment: This didn't work for me although it does sound quite logical.  I get the error "Cannot read property 'FIXTURES' of undefined" I am using handlebars and am outputting:
{{#each sponsorship in controller}}
{{sponsorship.sponsorshipName}}
{{sponsorship.partners}}
{{/each}}
Should I be using a different approach?

Comment: That error looks like `FIXTURES` is not defined. Check if the arrays you are assigning with are present before the assignment.

Comment: The thing is, if i drop {{sponsorship.partners}}, then my fixtures work just fine... it seems that i am targeting this related data incorrectly.  i tried to search for documentation on how to do this but couldn't find any.